# Should we just have one "master" question about Ether issuance?

Tags: discussion, support

A new one sprouted: [How many ethers will ever exist?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1223/42)

I'm not sure exactly which one to make it a dupe of:

[What is the expected Ether issuance schedule after transition to PoS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/644/42)

[What is the total supply of Ether?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/443/42)

Should we just have one "master" question about Ether issuance?  Close one as a dupe of the other.  Migrate/copy answers from one to the other if needed?

Comment: yes, we could merge the questions. only moderators can do that though.

Comment: @5chdn Vote here on your comment first?  Then we tag this question with [tag:support] ?

Comment: ok created a votable answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we could merge the questions since they answer the same topic. Only moderators can do that though.

Vote up for merge. Vote down for leaving them seperated.

Comment: give the vote couple more days?